# Excel VBA: Batch renaming sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to batch rename sheets in VBA:

Something like:

```
sheets(array(1, 2, 3)).name = array("hep", "hey", "heppa!")
```

naming sheets 1, 2, 3 as "hep", "hey" and "heppa!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Clearly it doesn't work directly
- And some experimentation with [SelectedSheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196933.aspx) didn't lead anywere

This is as close as I could get it, someone else may find a method to skip a loop

*[Updated with the standard way I would do this below including error handling - I hadn't actually tried setting a collection of sheets like this before]*

**`Normal Code`**

```
Sub Normal()
    Dim strShtOld()
    Dim strShtNew()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lngSht As Long
    strShtNew = Array("hep", "hey", "heppa!")
    strShtOld = Array("Sheet1", "Sheeta2", "Sheet3")
    On Error Resume Next
    For lngSht = LBound(strShtOld) To UBound(strShtOld)
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set ws = Sheets(strShtOld(lngSht))
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Name = strShtNew(lngSht)
    Next lngSht
End Sub
```

Why the batch rename, curiousity or do do you have such a large amount of renaming to do that you are concerned with code runtime?

**`Array Effort`**

```
    Sub ArrayEx()
    Dim varShts
    Dim varSht
    Dim strArray()
    strArray = Array("hep", "hey", "heppa!")
    Set varShts = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
    For varSht = 1 To varShts.Count
        varShts(varSht).Name = strArray(varSht - 1)
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: That's about what i ended up doing except i wasn't entirely sure of the array assignment shorthand

Comment: +1 this is totally optional but you could also Redim strArray and make it one-based so you wouldn't need to subtract one from it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pair of macros:

Macro 1:

```
Sub Sheetlist()
Dim x As Integer

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "sheetlist"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sheet List"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New List"
For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
Next x
End Sub
```

This macro creates a sheet in your current workbook called "sheetlist" with the list of all sheets in your current workbook. This sheet also has a column titled "New List" (C1) which you can enter as many sheet names as you want to rename.

What you can do now is eliminate the names from column A1 which you want to exclude from the renaming process. Make sure that there are no blanks in columns A and C, and that the number of names in A and C match as well.

Now you are ready to run the 2nd Macro:

```
Sub batchrename()
'
' batchrename Macro
'
Dim OldSheetName As String
Dim NewSheetName As String
Dim SheetCount As Integer
Dim NewSheetList As String

NewSheetList = InputBox("How many names are there?") + 1
For SheetCount = 1 To Range("C2:C" & NewSheetList).Count
OldSheetName = Sheets("sheetlist").Cells(SheetCount + 1, 1)
NewSheetName = Sheets("sheetlist").Cells(SheetCount + 1, 3)

Sheets(OldSheetName).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheetName
Next SheetCount

End Sub
```

This macro will go to the names listed in sheetlist A and change them to the names listed in sheetlist C. The prompt will ask you where the list of names are, input the number of names you have in column C, and hit enter.

Enjoy