# Iterating Through Workbook and Renaming Tabs

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel VBA: Batch renaming sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679615/excel-vba-batch-renaming-sheets)

Thanks for the help. I'm probably not iterating through appropriately. Maybe I should have assigned an integer to active sheet?

```
Sub TabNames()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ActiveSheet.Name = "herp"
Next ws
ActiveSheet.Name = "derp"
Next ws
ActiveSheet.Name = "herp derp"
Next ws
ActiveSheet.Name = "derp herp"
Next ws
ActiveSheet.Name = "herp herp"
Next ws
ActiveSheet.Name = "derp derp"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TabNames()

Dim arrNames, x as integer

arrNames = Array("herp", "herp derp", "derp herp", "herp herp", "derp derp")

For x = 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Name = arrNames(x-1)
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSheet` is the same sheet through your procedure, so you are just changing the current/visble worksheet's name over and over again.

use lines like this:

```
ws.Name = "herp"
```

etc...